# How to write long Pandas aggregations well?

Tags: python, pandas

**TL;DR**

How do you write long aggregations involving many operations like `groupby()`, `unstack()` or `apply()` well?

**Example**

Say you have a `DataFrame()` with `n_sales = 1000` ticket sales for `n_events = 10` different events, like

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sales = pd.DataFrame({
    'Event': np.random.choice(range(n_events), n_sales), 
    'Time': np.random.rand(n_sales)})
```

and you want to plot in how many events at least `n = [50, 100]` tickets were sold over the evening:
[image: # of events over time where at least x/y tickets were sold]

Then I would do

```
accumulation_of_sales = sales.groupby(['Time', 'Event']).size().unstack().fillna(0).cumsum()
events_with_n_sales = accumulation_of_sales.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(), axis=1).fillna(0)
events_with_geq_n_sales = events_with_n_sales[events_with_n_sales.columns[::-1]].cumsum(axis=1)

events_with_geq_n_sales[n].plot()
```

which seems hard to read to me and the lines are in principle too long (see [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)). So,

- how are this specific and similar operations done best?
- are there some tutorials/style guides/... for beginners? Maybe not particularly for Pandas, but similar languages?

Comment: In case you wonder why I might want to do this: I need to compare a stochastic model to experimental data with integer numbers as read out. So this is kind of a stacked histogram of the possible outcomes over time.

Answer (score 3):

One way to write multiline pandas queries is to use :

```
accumulation_of_sales = sales.groupby(['Time', 'Event'])\
                             .size()\
                             .unstack()\
                             .fillna(0)\
                             .cumsum()
```

*I sometimes prefer to wrap these in parenthesis instead.*

However, if you are doing several things here often there is a simpler way. For example, whenever you see "groupby + unstack" you should think "pivot_table":

```
sales.pivot_table(columns='Event', index='Time', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0).cumsum()
```

*(Which is equivalent, more efficient and more readable.)*

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Andy's method. I prefer using parenthesis **( )** for writing multiline statements

```
accumulation_of_sales = (sales.groupby(['Time', 'Event'])
                         .size()
                         .unstack()
                         .fillna(0)
                         .cumsum())
```